# How to send data back from a controller to a view in cakephp?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

In my view, I send a Ajax POST request along with data to the controller. Then, in the controller, it will receive the data and put it into a select query as an input to get data from database. Then, it will send the data received from database to the view to show up.

```
if( $this->request->is('ajax') ) {

        $this->autoRender = false;


            print_r($this->request->data);
            // get values from Ajax POST request here 
            $from=( $this->request->data('start_time'));
            $from = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($from));
            $to= $this->request->data('end_time');
            $to = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($to));
        //put data to a select query
                     .....
        //put all data received from database into $products
        $products = $this->Order->find('all',$option);
        Debugger::dump($products);
                    //send data to the view.
        $this->set('products',$products);
    //}
    }
```

I got all my needed data in $products, but when I sent it to view, it didnt show anything. Normally, the usual way is using:

```
$this->set('products',$products);
```

but here, I used for Ajax request:

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

so, that may be the reason why the data didnt show up, but then how can I send data to view?
please help me.

**Update:**
my view code is:

```
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>

            <tr>    
                <td><?php echo $product ['Discount']['product_id']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $this->Html->link($product['Product']['product_name'], array('controller'=>'products', 'action' => 'view', $product['Discount']['product_id'])); ?></td>
                <td>$<?php echo $product ['Order']['benefit']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $product ['Order']['number']; ?></td>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <?php endforeach; ?>
```

and my script for Ajax:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    var from = $('#from').val();
    var to = $('#to').val();
    alert(from+" "+to);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/project/cakephp/orders/hottest_products",
        type: 'POST',

        data: {"start_time": from, "end_time": to },
        beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Test-Header', 'test-value');},
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: First you need to remove autoRender from your control

Comment: ok. After removing, I see the data being changed in the Response of the fireBug, but it didnt change in the page.

Comment: and now debug $products on view

Comment: what do use mean by debug $products on view? Do you mean '$this->set('products',$products);' ?

Comment: try this debug($products); make sure debug mode is set 2 in Config/core.php

Comment: it returned something like that in the FireBug:
<div class="cake-debug-output">
<span><strong>/app/Controller/OrdersController.php</strong> (line <strong>82</strong>)</span>
<pre class="cake-debug">
array()
</pre>

Comment: it returned a query:
SELECT `Discount`.`product_id`, `Product`.`product_name`, (SUM(`Product`.`product_price` - `Discount`.`product_discount`)) AS `Order__benefit`, (COUNT(`Order`.`order_id`)) AS `Order__number` FROM `project`.`orders` AS `Order` INNER JOIN `project`.`discounts` AS `Discount` ON (`Order`.`discount_id` = `Discount`.`discount_id`) INNER JOIN `project`.`products` AS `Product` ON (`Discount`.`product_id` = `Product`.`product_id`) WHERE `Discount`.`start_time` >= '2012-11-27' AND `Discount`.`end_time` <= '2014-12-27' GROUP BY `Discount`.`product_id`, `Product`.`product_name`

Comment: Can you see values of $products in your action hottest_products ?

Comment: Actually the query above is from the first access to the page. After hitting the button, it didnt change.

Comment: You can check my page here http://cmpt470.csil.sfu.ca:8019/project/cakephp/orders/hottest_products  Account is: admin@hotmail.com and pass is 123456. After login, please access the link above again.

Comment: Actually it is not query is not sending data after ajax call. Can you please add few records of Orders ? 
Also there is a mistake $option is empty. Is this the complete action code ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a view in layouts called `ajax.ctp`

With the following contents:

```
<?php echo $content_for_layout?>
```

Then:

```
if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax()) {
      $this->layout = 'ajax';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should return data like

```
    Debugger::dump($products);
                //send data to the view.
    return $products;`
```

suggestion `return json_encode($products);` and decode in success method